# What is the difference between server key and legacy server key in FCM(Firebase cloud message )

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I little confused with the server key I have to use in the in the FCM. There are showing two server key now.Please check the screen shot of the page[image]

In the picture above shows the server key and legacy server key which one I have to use.Anyone has any idea what is the difference between the two?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*firebaser here*

We recently switched the format of the server key. The new keys are of a much longer format, which allows for more entropy.

The older format will continue to work, but we recommend that you switch to the new format.

Comment: Can we use the new server key in old GCM implementation as well?

Comment: Hi, Legacy keys could securized. New keys too?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen . No matter whether I use Server Key or Legacy Key to make a POST request using PostMan with the FCM legacy protocol, I get error "The request was missing an Authentication Key (FCM Token)" Could you please help me  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50486869

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen - I have two server keys and one legacy key listed in my fcm console for push notifications.  However, in my app none of those keys are listed in my google-services.json file - anywhere (should at least one of them be?).  Yet my app is still able to register new deviceIDs and subscribe users to topics.  Are all the serverKeys valid to use - or if not how can I tell which one I should be using?

Comment: The `google-services.json` contains configuration data for the client-side app. FCM server keys are meant to be used in a trusted environment, not in the app. Hence: these keys should *not* be in your `google-services.json`.  Your app uses one of the other values from `google-services.json` to subscribe, as far as I recall the `FCM_SENDER_ID` or something similar.