# How to send a POST request to Firebase Cloud Messaging API in Vapor

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, vapor

I am trying to make a POST request to a Firebase Notifications API using Vapor 1.5 and Firebase Legacy Protocol, but I get failure response.

> response is JSON(node: Node.Node.object(["multicast_id":
>   Node.Node.number(5936281277445399934), "failure": Node.Node.number(0),
>   "canonical_ids": Node.Node.number(0), "results":
>   Node.Node.array([Node.Node.object(["message_id":
>   Node.Node.string("0:1527074314969790%c7ade8b9f9fd7ecd")])]),
>   "success": Node.Node.number(1)]))

**EDIT** 
Making the request through POSTMan fails with error "The request was missing an Authentication Key (FCM Token)."

```
class FirebaseRequester {
 let fcmLegacyServerKey = "AIzaSyDSuXXXXXXkCafTQay5_r8j3snvVos"

 func sendNotification(payLoad: JSON) throws -> Response {

    var response: Response?
    do {
        let responseFCM = try drop.client.post("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", 
           headers: ["Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization": "key\(fcmLegacyServerKey)"], 
           query: [:], 
          body: payLoad.makeBody())

        response = responseFCM

    }catch let error {
        let message = error.localizedDescription
        logErr.prints(message: message)
        throw Abort.custom(status: .badRequest, message: message)
    }

    guard let rsp = response?.json else {


        let message = "no json received on line \(#line)"
        drop.log.error(message)
        logErr.prints(message: message)
        throw Abort.custom(status: .badRequest, message: message)
     }
  print("rsp in json format is \(rsp)")
      return response!
 }//end of sendNotification()
}//end of class FirebaseRequester




      //make another class here and initialize it with  FirebaseRequester
      //get data from Client App 
      // validate data 
      // finally, create the payLoad and call sendNotification(:)
     //request should look like 
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": "Breaking News!",
    "sound": "default",
    "link_url": "https://raywenderlich.com"
 }
}

     let fcmKeyToSendTo = "someDeviceTokenKeyReceivedFromClient_biHZNI-e9E53WEkCzrki"

            let data = try Node(node: ["alert": "alert", "sound": "sound", "link_url": "https://www.someWebsite.com"])

     var payLoadObj = try JSON(node: ["aps" : data])
     payLoadObj["to"] = try JSON(node: fcmKeyToSendTo)

            do {
                let _ = try firebaseRequester.sendNotification(payLoad: payLoadObj)
            }catch{
                logErr.prints(message: error.localizedDescription)
            }

            let message = "notification Sent"
            return try JSON(node:["success":message])
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey bibscy. Saw your comment from your previous post and got here. I haven't used vapor before, but should the Authorization value be formatted like `"key\(fcmLegacyServerKey)"`? shouldn't it be the plain server key value? If that doesn't work, maybe follow the format for when sending it via postman i.e. `"key=(fcmLegacyServerKey)"`?

Comment: @AL. I had attached a screenshot from PostMan, and that request returns 401 too. That should return 200. Now, back to your question   fcmLegacyServerKey: String is a variable, so using "key=\(fcmLegacyServerKey) is legal, in essence it's like "key=123456AA"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In `sendNotification(payload:)` I had a typo, I missed `=` after key. It should have been `"key=\(fcmLegacyServerKey)"`
2. In `sendNotification(payload:)`, `payLoad.makeBody` should not be called, I should have just passed the JSON object `payLoad` as an argument to the .post request.
3. The JSON object of the notification was clearly badly formatted from the outset. The message type I wanted to send was *notification*, but I was passing in a key named `aps`. I should have passed key `notification` as shown below.

> .

```
class FirebaseRequester {

  let fcmLegacyServerKey = "AIzaSy....vVos"

  func sendNotification(payLoad: JSON) throws -> Response {

  var response: Response?
   do {
     let responseFCM = try drop.client.post("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", 
       headers: ["Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization": "key=\(fcmLegacyServerKey)"], 
       query: [:], 
      body: payLoad

      response = responseFCM

  }catch let error {
     let message = error.localizedDescription
     logErr.prints(message: message)
     throw Abort.custom(status: .badRequest, message: message)
 }
   guard let rsp = response?.json else {

    let message = "no json received on line \(#line)"
    drop.log.error(message)
    logErr.prints(message: message)
    throw Abort.custom(status: .badRequest, message: message)
   }
    return response!
  }//end of sendNotification()
}//end of class FirebaseRequester



class TestRouteNow {

  let firebaseRequester: FirebaseRequester

  init(firebaseRequester: FirebaseRequester) {
     self.firebaseRequester = firebaseRequester
  }

  func addRoutes(drop: Droplet) {
     drop.post("test", "notif", handler: postNotification)
  }

   func postNotification(request: Request) throws -> ResponseRepresentable {

   let fcmDevice = "someDeviceTokenReceivedFromClientApp"
   let data = try Node(node: ["title": "title","body": "body", "sound": "default", "badge":"60"])

    var payLoadObj = try JSON(node: ["notification": data])
    payLoadObj["to"] = try JSON(node: fcmDevice)

      do {
        let _ = try firebaseRequester.sendNotification(payLoad: payLoadObj)
            }catch{
                logErr.prints(message: error.localizedDescription)
            }

            let message = "notification Sent"
            return try JSON(node:["success":message]) 
     } 
 }//end of class




    // request body
{
  "to" : "cQDtm_someDeviceTokenReceivedFromClient",
  "priority":"high",

 "notification": {
     "title":"Booking Rescheduled",
      "body": "Cancelled Booking 7830593, for Mon, 12 March",
      "sound":"default",
     "badge": "100"
  }
}
```